# cpu usage goes up when i move mouse to show xy coordinates

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I want to show x , y coordinates when i mouse move over map in a webgis .The problem is whenever i move the mouse, the cpu usage goes up to a maximum of 40%.Is there any solution to reduce cpu usage?

I'm using ArcGIS API silverlight 3.1 , ArcGIS server 10.1 , sql server 2008 R2 , windows 7

Comment: What is the projection of your map? How are you reading and displaying the X & Y coordinates?

Comment: What happens if you create a map with only a basemap and no other layers - does the usage still go up on mouse-move?

Comment: The projection of map is UTM . I'm using th esri sample https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#MouseCoords

Comment: @StephenLead i have some layers and i should use these in my web . I don't have any basemap .